# Fully qualified interface name in inheritance

Tags: c#

There are 2 interfaces defined as:

```
interface calc1
{
    int add(int a, int b);
}
interface calc2
{
    int add(int x, int y);
}
```

A class implements both these interfaces as:

```
class Calculation : calc1, calc2
{
    public int result1;
    public virtual int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return result1 = a + b;
    }        
}
```

Everything works fine. But when I change class definition as:

```
class Calculation : calc1, calc2
{
    public int result1;
    public int result2;
    public virtual int calc1.add(int a, int b)
    {
        return result1 = a + b;
    }

    public int calc2.add(int x, int y)
    {
        return result2 = x - y;
    }
}
```

I see errors:

```
The modifier 'virtual' is not valid for this item
```

and

```
The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
```

What is wrong in the latter class code?

Comment: Why do you need the method to be `virtual`? are you planning on inheriting from `Calculation`? Do you only need one of the two methods to be virtual?

Comment: Yes. As I cannot post the original code I have altered it before posting over here. I only want one of the 2 methods to be virtual as I am going to override it in derived class.

Comment: You can make the first one an implicit implementation (`public virtual int add(int a, int b)`) and the second one an explicit implementation (`int calc2.add(int x, int y)`)

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit interface implementations can't have an access modifier, since they are only visible when using the interface as a type. There is no point in making it `public`.

Also, you can't derived from an explicit interface implementation, so `virtual` is useless too. The compiler knows that and breaks on it.